# Debug.Assert in exception unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have some inner logic of my library. Before I used expressions like this to check input data of my inner logic:

```
if (value < 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value");
```

But my library is very performance-sensetive, so now I use expressions like this only for my API to check user input.
Inner input for my inner code I check with Debug.Assert to save several percent of performace in release.

But now, my unit tests of my inner code which check invalid input doesn't work. With Debug.Assert there is not any exception more.
So how can I check Debug.Assert in my unit tests?

Comment: Well, it can't because you don't actually have any kind of checks. Have you considered using [CodeContracts](https://github.com/Microsoft/CodeContracts) to make your code provably only take valid inputs? It should work just like Debug.Assert so the code won't exist in the release version but you can prove none of your code passes in a invalid value.

Comment: When I said "you don't actually have any kind of checks" I meant your unit tests are likely working against a "Release" build of the program, when in release mode all functions in the `System.Diagnostics.Debug` class become NO-OPs and don't do anything.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thanks a lot!
Code contracts is exactly what I need!

Comment: Changed my comment in to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it can't because you don't actually have any kind of checks, your unit tests are likely working against a "Release" build of the program, when in release mode all functions in the `System.Diagnostics.Debug` class become NO-OPs and don't do anything.

Have you considered using [CodeContracts](https://github.com/Microsoft/CodeContracts) to make your code provably only take valid inputs? It should work just like `Debug.Assert` so the code won't exist in the release version but you can prove none of your code passes in a invalid value.